# Anonymous record type inside discriminated union

Tags: f#, algebraic-data-types

The F# tutorial includes the following snippet:

```
/// A record for a person's first and last name
type Person = {     
    First : string
    Last  : string
}

/// define a discriminated union of 3 different kinds of employees
type Employee = 
    | Engineer  of Person
    | Manager   of Person * list<Employee>            // manager has list of reports
    | Executive of Person * list<Employee> * Employee // executive also has an assistant
```

The fact that Manager and Executive are described as tuples offends my sensibilities (I'm easily offended).  It strikes me as not terribly expressive.  I tried to modify them as follows:

```
/// define a discriminated union of 3 different kinds of employees
type Employee = 
    | Engineer  of Person
    | Manager   of { Name: Person; Reports: Employee list }            // manager has list of reports
    | Executive of { Name: Person; Reports: Employee list; Assistant: Employee}   // executive also has an assistant
```

Sadly, the definitions of Manager and Executive now give an error: "This construct is deprecated; consider using a separate record type instead." Ok, seems fair, let's call it ManagerType. But wait ... ManagerType refers to Employee (for the Reports part), and Employee refers to ManagerType (for the Manager option).

Is there a solution here?  Is it not possible for two data structures to be defined in terms of each other?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can define mutually dependent types using `and`:

```
    type Employee = 
    | Engineer  of Person
    | Manager   of Manager            // manager has list of reports
    | Executive of Executive
    and Manager = { Name: Person; Reports: Employee list }
    and Executive = { Name: Person; Reports: Employee list; Assistant: Employee }
```

Comment: Interesting. Can we use inheritance too? Can Executive derive from Manager? Or does this only work with Records?

Answer (score 14):

If you're using F# v3.1 you can use [named union fields <sup>[MSDN]</sup>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233226.aspx) (and protect your delicate sensibilities):

```
type Employee = 
    | Engineer  of Person
    | Manager   of Name: Person * Reports: Employee list
    | Executive of Name: Person * Reports: Employee list * Assistant: Employee
```

Comment: This solution isn't bad (it does avoid distressing my weak constitution), but what would it look like in a pattern matching expression if I wanted to extract only the Reports, let's say, from a Manager?  Using the other solutions it would be: `| Manager ({Reports=rep}) -> whatever`.

Comment: I don't have v3.1 installed but according to the MSDN page linked in my answer it would be `| Manager (Reports=rep) -> ...`.

Comment: It would look like this

Manager (Person, Report)

the onlye difference is that you can name them

Answer (score 8):

Mutually recursive types are declared with `type ... = ... and ... = ...`:

```
type Employee = 
    | Engineer  of Person
    | Manager   of Manager 
    | Executive of Executive
and Manager = { Name: Person; Reports: Employee list }
and Executive = { Name: Person; Reports: Employee list; Assistant: Employee}
```

Comment: Sorry; Lee snuck it in slightly faster :)

Answer (score 6):

As of FSharp 4.6 you can use [Anonymous Records](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/anonymous-records#embedding-anonymous-records-within-other-types) with unions. So with your example can be defined in this way:

```
type Person = {     
    First : string
    Last  : string
}

type Employee =
    | Engineer of Person
    | Manager of {| Name: Person; Reports: Employee list |}
    | Executive of {| Name: Person; Reports: Employee list; Assistant: Employee |}
```

Comment: For completeness: anonymous records cannot be pattern matched ([yet](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/713)).